# asp.net gridview control is going back to the gridview rather than showing panels on edit button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am working on a project in asp.net. I have a  gridview that contains employee's names, designation and department. when i click on the edit button on any row gridview gets hide and the second div is visible that contains different buttons like address, education, trainings etc.Each button shows the specific panel to add or edit the data. But the issue is when i click on any button, the control goes back to the gridview rather than showing the appropriate panel it shows the gridview which was hide. I am using OnEditCommand property of the gridview to hide the gridview and show the other div.How to resolve this issue?
[asp.net gridvew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnjtX.png)
[divs to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smeGc.png)

Comment: Please provide some code - without it noone can tell you exaclty what is wrong.

Comment: 2 images are added in the post Nikolai. plz check them